# Populating a list using Foreign Key Values in MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a prototype platform using MVC in which users can make a profile and use that profile to make text posts, like a social media site. I have the following two tables in my database:

Profiles

```
 public partial class Profile
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Profile()
    {
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Country_ { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DoB { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

}

Posts

```
public partial class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

}

In my ViewModel I have a list of Posts called PostList, which I want to populate with all of the Post records made by the user. So, I need to populate the list with all records where the ProfileId in Posts is equal to the Id of Profile, which is determined by whether or not the UserId in Profile is equal to the current user's Identity.

In short, I need:

Post List = Posts where ProfileId = Profiles.Id Where Profiles.UserId = CurrentUserId.

Any ideas? I've tried the following, but it's totally wrong:

```
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        ViewModels.ProfileViewModel pVm = new ViewModels.ProfileViewModel();
        pVm.PostList = db.Posts.Include(db.Profiles).Where(a => a.UserId ==    userId).ToList();
        pVm.UserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        return View(pVm);
```

Comment: please show your Profiles and Posts models

Comment: Updated with the Profile and Posts models from the Entity Model :)

Comment: You're not doing what you said you should be doing, you're comparing Posts `UserId` to `userId` right now, but in your text you've said it should compare Posts `ProfileId`  to `userId`.  So it should be `pVm.PostList = db.Posts.Include(db.Profiles).Where(a => a.ProfileId ==  userId).ToList();`

Comment: userId and profileId are different though. UserId is User.Identity.GetUserId stored in a table to associate the user to a profile. ProfileId on the other hand, just points to the particular profile that a post is associated with. So each userId has an associated profileId, which in turn is associated to one or more Posts. Wouldn't this equate ProfileId and userId as the same thing?

Comment: I've updated the post to hopefully make the problem a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You just walk the relationship in your query:

```
pVm.PostList = db.Posts.Where(a => a.Profile.UserId == userId);
```

It's unnecessary to use `Include` since `Profile` will automatically be joined to make the query.